# Node.js | MongoDB count(): Getting Count Before and After Inserting Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get the counts of items in a database to confirm that data insertion is successful.

1. Get count before insert
2. Insert
3. Get count after insert
4. Console.log a summary

Note: I know this can be implemented using some simple functions:

```
dbName.equal(insertSize, result.insertedCount)
```

However, I am new to javascript and I think I've come across a need to implement asynchronous callbacks, so I wanted to figure this out.

**Insert Function**

```
var insertMany = function() {

    // get initial count
    var count1 = getDbCount();

    // Insert new 'data'
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        var col = db.collection(collectionName);
        col.insert(data, {w:1}, function(err,result) {});
        db.close();
    });

    /** This needs to be implemented through next/callback
        after the insert operation  **/
    var count2 = getDbCount(); 

    /** These final console logs should be executed after all
        other operations are completed **/    
    console.log('[Count] Start: ' + count1 + ' | End:' +count2);
    console.log('[Insert] Expected: ' + data.length + ' | Actual: ' + (count2 - count1));

};
```

**Get DB Count Function**

```
var getDbCount = function() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        var col = db.collection(collectionName);

        col.count({}, function(err, count) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            db.close();
            console.log('docs count: ' + count);
            // This log works fine
        });

    });

    return count; // this is returning as undefined since this is
                  // executing before the count operation is completed
};
```

I am getting errors because the returns are occurring before the required operations have completed.

Thanks for your help.

---

**[EDIT] getCount Function with Promise**

I have added the promise to the getCount function as a start:

```
var getCount = function() {

    var dbCount = 0;

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to server', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Database connection established:' + dbName);
            }

            // Get the collection
            var col = db.collection(collectionName);

            col.count({}, function(err, count) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                db.close();
                console.log('docs count: ' + count);
                resolve(null);
                dbCount = count;
            });

        });

    });

    promise.then(function() {
        return dbCount;
    });

};

console.log(getCount());
```

The output is still:
    undefined
    Database connection established:testdb
    docs count: 500

Then then({return count}) code is still being executed before the promise {db.count()}.  It returns undefined before the database operations are completed.

Comment: It's kinda hart to tell what you did wrong if you dont show what you tried. The error should come with some information on which line the error occured. Provide the code block in which the error occured and the part where it is called at least

Comment: Hi newBee, I've taken that out.  I didn't make much progress on implementing through callbacks, which is why I didn't include it.  If I make progress, I'll update and add the new code.  Thanks

Comment: @CarloP.LasMarias you should never settle on `setTimeout`. There are a lot of articles explaining the atrocity of the function specially in the backend. Promise is a module developed to handle such conditions, and if it doesn't work, the problem is in the code somewhere which needs to be figured out. Async.js is another far better option than `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the problem you have is that you expect the value to be already there when your functions return. Well with async functions this is often not the case. There is a huge amount of information about async processing (not to be mistaken with parallel processing like in Java).

I have created an example which should fit your situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/rh3gx76x/1/

```
var dummyCount = 5
getCount = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() { // this would be your db call, counting your documents
          resolve(dummyCount); // dummy for number of documents found
      }, 100 * Math.random());
  });
};

insertMany = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() { // this would be your db call, writing your documents
          dummyCount += 2;
          resolve();
      }, 100 * Math.random());
  });
};

runIt = function(callback) {
   var count1;
   getCount().then(function(count) {
        console.log("First callback with value ", count);
      count1 = count;
        insertMany().then(function() {
         getCount().then(function(count2){
            console.log("Second callback with value ", count2);
                callback(null, count1, count2);
         });
      })
   })
}

runIt(function(err, count1, count2) {
   console.log("count1: " + count1 + ", count2: " + count2);
});
```

One last thing. You might want to check out the "async" package. This helps a lot with those problems providing a lot of helper functions and control flow stuff.

Comment: `setTimeout` is an awful practice. It is not recommended to use timeout specially in I/O tasks. You are eating up a shift of time by randomly delaying the code. This would eat up your resources while developing complex websites.

Comment: @Ritik Saxena the timeout here is just a replacement for the db calls the original poster made which makes the sample easier to read. Cannot follow you on the resource issue you are mentioning neither. Delaying code into the next event loop tick is not that uncommon. Although you would then always use a timeout of "0" of course.

Comment: @newBee by using setTimeout as a replacement for the db calls to make the sample easier to read, I'm hoping you didn't mean that you added it to make the sample more readable, without any other purpose. did you? Moreover, `reject` is used to pass errors in promises, which are handled in catch statements. So, you might want to edit the comment `null = no error`, because null here means the code has nothing to pass to `then`.

Comment: @newBee I'm not exactly getting why you used the timeout. And actually, timeout is an uncommon practice at back-end. In this case your code might work, but in a scenario where the amount of time taken by the program to read/write database depends on the size of database, you will set a random time for timeout and hope for the best to happen. So, your code might work here but it is not a good practice to be followed throughout.

Comment: @RitikSaxena wrt your 1st reply: I am not passing back a Promise when calling the runIt function. You misunderstood the flow of the program. In general using a promise or callback approach is a matter of preference. The timeout here is just to simulate any async operation (e.g. disk IO or DB calls) and hence providing a more generic example.
w.r.t your 2nd question: there are use cases where you need those (or similiar functions like setImmediate). E.g. when calling a lot of callbacks in one tick. This can cause a ```stack overflow``` error.

Comment: @newBee you didn't need to simulate async code (like in documentation) here because the db call was itself an async call. Since you did it to simulate the async call here, the argument has no point. But the poster has mentioned in his chat that he relied on using timeouts inspired by your answer, which he did not need to use here. Moreover, your response to my 1st reply didn't clarify why you wrote `null=no error`, which is wrong actually, resolve doesn't account for `errors`.

Comment: @RitikSaxena regrading the ```null=...``` yepp sorry. When i wrote the sample I started off with regular callbacks but switches to Promises. Forgot to edit the comments. ```"you didn't need to simulate async code"``` didn't have to but then try to run it in jsfiddle (so some1 can play around with it) where you do not have the ```MongoClient``` for example. Also code comments tell, that the timeouts are *replace* the db calls in this example. You were not supposed to *add* both.

Comment: @newBee actually you should have mentioned it clearly that the timeouts are for simulation and to be replaced in real code. When I had a discussion with the one who posted this question, I came to know he was actually using timeouts in his code, and even I was disguised by the code, due to not mentioning clearly. Maybe you should edit the comments to provide a better experience. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the returns are occurring before the operations have completed is the `asynchronous` design of nodejs, inherited from javascript. The callback from `Mongoose.connect()` is left to do the operation while the program moves forward and encounters the `return`.

You have not provided your workaround which landed you in the error statement so I can't comment on what wrong you've done there. But, considering your first effort to finish what you started, the best approach to ensure that the `Mongoose.connect()` completes and then the return statement executes is using JavaScript's  [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Using promises will make your `Mongoose.connect()` execute and then pass the control to the return statement.

Your code will go something like:

**Insert function**:

```
var insertMany = function() {

// get initial count
var count1 = getDbCount();

// Insert new 'data'
var promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve,reject){
      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        var col = db.collection(collectionName);
        col.insert(data, {w:1}, function(err,result) {});
        db.close();
        resolve(null);
      });
    }
  );
  promise.then(function(val){    
    var count2 = getDbCount();

    /** These final console logs should be executed after all
    other operations are completed **/
    console.log('[Count] Start: ' + count1 + ' | End:' +count2);
    console.log('[Insert] Expected: ' + data.length + ' | Actual: ' + (count2 - count1));
});
```

Similarly, you can add promise to `GetDB` function.
The keypoints while executing a promise are:

1. `then()` contains the part of function to be executed synchronously after the execution of promise. It is called by `resolve`, and the parameter passed is received in `catch` function's callback.
2. `catch()` contains the part of function which is called when error is encountered in a promise. It is called by `reject`, and the parameter passed is received in `catch` function's callback.

**EDIT:** An alternative of promise is [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html), only differing in the fact that it is an external module, unlike promises.

Comment: be aware that this code will still fail. count2 will have the value "undefined"

Comment: @newBee After the code I've written, I've mentioned that the `GetDB` also has to be executed in this manner. Then, the count will have a value to return to count2.

Comment: Thanks @RitikSaxena, I tried this but still getting the same error. Even after adding the promise, the then statements are still executing before the promise.  I've added above the revised getCount.

Comment: @CarloP.LasMarias you are calling the `resolve` and then assigning the `dbCount` a value. So your `dbCount` never gets assigned. Try this: replace `null` with `count` inside resolve. In `then` function's callback, receive a paramter and assign it to `dbCount`

Comment: @RitikSaxena I've tried  resolve(count); dbCount = count;, and reversed order also.  Still the same result, dbCount = undefined.

Comment: have you added `promise` in both the functions?

Comment: @RitikSaxena I just did it on getCount first, because that function also needs it.  So the promise is running the db.count() method, then is returning this count.  Even after I added the promise.then(return count), return count is still being executed first, before the db.count() has completed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133719/discussion-between-ritik-saxena-and-carlo-p-las-marias).