# javascript asynchronuous functions

Tags: javascript, callback, return

I'm new to javascript, i wanted to check some data using google maps api but this asynchronuous execution of function is killing me, and i don't really understand how callbacks work. Tried to do it but doesn't work.

```
function initMap(a, callback) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [punktpocz[a], punktpocz[a + 1]],
        destinations: [punktkonc[a], punktkonc[a + 1]],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status !== 'OK') {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else {
            var originList = response.originAddresses;
            var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
            for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    theDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
                        ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
                        results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
                    wynik.push({ odl: results[j].distance.text, czas: results[j].duration.text });
                }
            }
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

and in the second function:

```
for(i=0;i<czasmax;i++){     
    ...
    punktpocz.push(kie[id-1]);
    punktkonc.push(biz[parseInt(zleceniajava[z+1])]);
    punktpocz.push(biz[parseInt(zleceniajava[z+1])]);
    punktkonc.push( zle[ parseInt(zleceniajava[z])] );

    initMap(i*2,function(){
        console.log('huzzah, I\'m done!');
     });
     ...        
    }
```

and  i want for the script to wait until initmap is finished to continue but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using promises (I had a similar question before: [Javascript Promise/Then Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792914/javascript-promise-then-example)) or use [async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

([Node.js | MongoDB count(): Getting Count Before and After Inserting Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781807/node-js-mongodb-count-getting-count-before-and-after-inserting-data))